# Did Keuller use Force lightning in The New Rebellion?

Tags: star-wars

I don't have access to *The New Rebellion* book and Google books doesn't provide enough details about Keuller's use of Force lightning<sup>[1](https://books.google.com/books?id=5SXqEN0BAcYC&q=force+lightning#v=onepage&q=force%20lightning&f=false)</sup>. Can anybody tell me if Keuller uses Force lightning in the book. The reason I ask, is that Wookieepedia lists it in the book's appearances box<sup>[2](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_New_Rebellion)</sup>.

Comment: AFAIK, no. I read it recently, but I could have missed a detail like that.

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's not worded well, but it's not deserving of dvs.

Comment: @SSumner - haters gonna hate. Although in case of thise Q I'm tempted to DV myself. The tone, as they say, sucks

Comment: I don't recall force lightning being tossed around by Keuller, but it's been a while since I've read the novel. From what I do recall, Keuller relied on bombs, technology, subterfuge, manipulation, telekinesis, and his skills with a lightsaber. Also: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kueller

Answer (score 1):

Using [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=rqjdeIK1cogC&printsec=frontcover&dq=isbn:0553574140&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cRHCUdLFBIeorQHS5ICoAg&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false), I did a text search inside *The New Rebellion* for the word "lightning". The only occurrence is on page 515 (Google Books page number), which reads:

> The Star Destroyer exploded: white and red and yellow against the blackness of space. A flower opening, a **lightning** bolt expanding, a fire starting and ending all in the space of a heartbeat. Beautiful and terrible at the very same time.

So it's safe to say it is an error in the Wookieepedia page, and Keuller does *not* use force lightning.